# Checking what files would be added in directory

Tags: git

Suppose you are thinking of adding some new files with `git add .` and want to make sure that `.gitignore` is correct first, to not pick up files that shouldn't be picked up, like object code. In the normal course of events, `git status` will do this job.

But what if the files are in a new directory? In that case, `git status` just shows `foo/`.

How do you list what files in the directory would be added by `git add .`?

Comment: Just do `git add .`, then check what is staged.  If you don't like it, do `git reset`

Comment: `git status -uall`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also try:

```
git add --dry-run .
```

which *don’t* actually add the files, just show if they exist or will be ignored (shorter version: `-n`).